# fixed sized iframe in responsive design

Tags: html, css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a couple of iframes from http://snapwidget.com. The issue is that they are fixed size and are not playing nice with twitter bootstrap. Is there a way I could get them to resize? Or at the very least have my other divs not under/overlap them when the screen size shifts, but rather move around them?

index.html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span8 stayright">
                <!-- SnapWidget desktop-->
                <div class="instagram_desktop">
                    <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/mp/?u=ZGVudmVyc3RyZWV0aGVhcnR8aW58NzcwfDJ8M3x8eWVzfDV8bm9uZQ==" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:770px; height: 770px" ></iframe>
                </div>
                <!-- SnapWidget ipad-->
                <div class="instagram_inbetween">          
                    <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/mp/?u=ZGVudmVyc3RyZWV0aGVhcnR8aW58NjIwfDJ8M3x8eWVzfDV8bm9uZQ==" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:620px; height: 620px" ></iframe>
                </div>
                <!-- SnapWidget ipad profile-->
                <div class"instagram_ipad_p">
                    <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/mp/?u=ZGVudmVyc3RyZWV0aGVhcnR8aW58NDc2fDJ8M3x8eWVzfDV8bm9uZQ==" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:476px; height: 476px" ></iframe>
                </div>
                <!-- SnapWidget iphone-->
                <div class"instagram_iphone"
                    <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/mp/?u=ZGVudmVyc3RyZWV0aGVhcnR8aW58MzcwfDJ8M3x8eWVzfDV8bm9uZQ==" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:370px; height: 370px" ></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4 stayleft small1">
                <img src="../../Sites/Boiler%20Plate/img/joshmays.jpg" alt="joshmays" width="370" height="370">
            </div>
            <div class="span4 stayleft small2">
                <img src="../../Sites/Boiler%20Plate/img/joshmays.jpg" alt="joshmays" width="370" height="370">
            </div>
            <div class="span8 big2">
                <!-- SnapWidget -->
                <iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/in/?u=ZGVudmVyc3RyZWV0aGVhcnR8aW58NzYwfDF8MXx8eWVzfDB8bm9uZQ==" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:770px; height: 770px" ></iframe>
            </div>

            <div class="span4 r2 small1">
                <img src="../../Sites/Boiler%20Plate/img/joshmays.jpg" alt="joshmays" width="370" height="370">

            </div>
            <div class="span4 small2">
                <img src="../../Sites/Boiler%20Plate/img/joshmays.jpg" alt="joshmays" width="370" height="370">

            </div>

            <div class="span4 r3 small1">
                <h2>Something Else</h2>
                <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.stayright {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.stayleft {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.small1 {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.small2 {
    padding: 15px 0 25px 0; 
}

.big2 {
    padding: 25px 0px;
}

.r2 .small1 {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.big2 {
    margin-top: -25px;  
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
.instagram_iphone { display: none !important; }
.instagram_ipad_p { display: none !important; }
.instagram_inbetween { display: none !important; }
.instagram_iphone_ls { display: none !important; }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 769px) {
.instagram_iphone { display: none !important; }
.instagram_ipad_p { display: none !important; }
.instagram_desktop { display: none !important; }
.instagram_iphone_ls { display: none !important; }
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 481px) {
.instagram_desktop { display: none !important; }
.instagram_inbetween { display: none !important; }
.instagram_iphone { display: none !important; }
.instagram_iphone_ls { display: none !important; }
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 321px) {
.instagram_desktop { display: none !important; }
.instagram_ipad_p { display: none !important; }
.instagram_inbetween { display: none !important; }
.instagram_iphone { display: none !important; }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
.instagram_iphone_ls { display: none !important; }
.instagram_desktop { display: none !important; }
.instagram_inbetween { display: none !important; }
.instagram_ipad_p { display: none !important; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using % values in `style` attribute?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I have. The iframe stayed at its output dimensions. Unless I need to put it at a % in relation to something else? Which I'm not sure how to do, or if that's what you should do.

Comment: try this CSS to see if its working : `iframe{width: 100% !important;}` !important isnt a good approach but i like it when it come to testing CSS override.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon That appears to be working width-wise, but when trying to keep the height of the iframes proportional using `height: auto;` in conjunction with `width: 100% !important;` the iframes shrunk way down to about 120px.

Comment: Then, you absolutly need jquery to resize it, tell me if you want me to do the code.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon If you could please I would very much appreciate it. I have also updated the post so that it shows the media queries I am trying should that help. Trying this guys attempt: http://scottwebb.me/blog/2012/07/01/responsive-snapwidget/#comment-306 but they all show up at once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after looking for the widget, i am able to resize it, but the inside of the widget isnt responsive so it's useless.

The only other possible way is the one that you are using (mediaqueries) but it is not working for those 2 reasons:

```
<!-- SnapWidget ipad profile-->
            <div class"instagram_ipad_p">
```

Class is missing an = (`class=""`)

```
<!-- SnapWidget iphone-->
            <div class"instagram_iphone"
```

`div` isnt closing (`<div>`) and class is missing an =.

After those modification, your mediaqueries will work! [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VhHhM/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has this nice method called resize.  You could do something like.  (Code no tested)

```
//initially set the iframe's width to the window size
mtarget = getElementById... //get the iframe
mtarget.width = $(window).width;

$(window).resize(function() {
//and again...set the width of the iframe to $(window).width()...?
});
```

In theory, that should help your iframe to place nice

Comment: I'm still pretty green when it comes to web design. I know minimal jQuery, but I will play around with this and see. Currently I'm trying to set multiple sizes of iframes and call them in media queries.